# Convert Html to Pdf using Rotativa in AspNetCore

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm using `rotativa` for generate view to pdf in asp net core 2.0.

It works fine to generate, my doubt is about response. If I use this block of code works, it automatically do download when I click button:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Get, new { @action = action , @class="block"}))
{
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
}
```

But I need to send the request by `ajax`. It works too, but I don't know how to download file when the data is returned. For example, follow the `ajax` request:

```
function pdf() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: {
            'Id': Id,
            'p': p
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            console.log('Wait...');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Success! (I need to download file here)')
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the code I'm using to generate in server:

```
return new ViewAsPdf(view, obj) { FileName = product + ".pdf" };
```

Answer (score 1):

It is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45968028/4696508)

You can create an anchor element on the fly and click it programmatically or use [Download js](http://danml.com/download.html)